# set x axis text labels from data file in pgf plots

Tags: pgfplots

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents}{horizontal.dat}
Name Self PR ST PA CO TO
RS 95.8 87.8 94.6 99.2 87.4 91.9
MS 99.2 84.6 91.1 100.0 91.0 91.0
SM 83.4 65.6 72.2 62.5 77.4 71.4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{horizontal.dat}{\horizontal}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xtick=data,
            xticklables from table={\horizontal}{Name}
        ]
        \addplot table [
        x=Name,
      y=TO] {\horizontal};

        \addplot table [
        x=Name,
      y=Self] {\horizontal};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

All I am trying to do is draw a bar chart with whatever appears in under Name as X axis, whatever appears in Self as data for 1st bar and whatever appears in TO as data for 2nd bar.

So, against RS on X axis, there will be two bars. One for 95.8 and the other for 91.9, etc.

It keeps telling me RS is not a floating point number!

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

This an attempt. `pgfplotstable` is required. This solution use `foreach` loop to read the data.

Note: Use of `horizontal.dat` input via `filecontents` will work too.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

%\begin{filecontents}{horizontal.dat}
%Name Self PR ST  PA CO TO
%RS 95.8 87.8 94.6 99.2 87.4 91.9
%MS 99.2 84.6 91.1 100.0  91.0 91.0
%SM 83.4 65.6 72.2 62.5 77.4 71.4
%\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

%\pgfplotstableread{horizontal.dat}{\horizontal}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Name,Self,PR,ST, PA,CO,TO
RS,95.8,87.8,94.6,99.2,87.4,91.9
MS,99.2,84.6,91.1,100.0, 91.0,91.0
SM,83.4,65.6,72.2,62.5,77.4,71.4
}\horizontal


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
    height=10cm,
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.3,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\horizontal}{Name},
    x tick label style={anchor=north,font=\small}
    ]
\foreach \i in {Self,PR,ST,PA,CO,TO}
{\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=\i] {\horizontal}; }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just two questions. Why did you change filecontent way of inputting data? It works even with that. Secondly, is there any way to automate \foreach \i in {Self, PR, ST, PA, CO, TO} part? I mean, the items are taken automatically from \horizontal

Comment: Hi, To be honest with you, I failed first time when compling your way of input, so I changed to the way I am comfortable with. After that I went back to try your way of input. So after confirmation, I reported both worked. As to the second question, I don't recall any right out of my head, but there are few questions asked on this site with that automation concerns.